# Is there a way to optimize Rust filters for iterators like SQL queries?

Tags: database, optimization, rust, query-optimization

I noticed that Rust iterators can somewhat resemble SQL queries. As I am not familiar with SQL nor it’s optimizations (though I am familiar that there is indeed heavy optimization of queries), is there a way for Rust or any other language to optimize iteration style filters compile time? For example,

```rust
struct City {
    population: u64,
    name: String,
}

fn heavy_computation_criteria(population: u64) -> bool {
    unimplemented!();
}

fn main() {
    let cities = vec![ ... ];
    let matches = cities
        .iter()
        .filter(|city| heavy_computation_criteria(city.population))
        .filter(|city| city.population > 1000)
        .map(|city| city.name);
}
```

Is similar to something like

```sql
SELECT name FROM cities WHERE population > 1000 AND cities.heavy_computation_criteria(cities.population)
```

I would imagine SQL would first filter via population rather than the heavy computation criteria. Is there such an optimization method in rust?

Comment: Are you asking if Rust does or could reorder these filters? Or are you asking how you would design a system that would behave as such?

Comment: I am asking both, I should have clarified. I wonder if rust can / already does such optimizations, and if not how such a system would be implemented on a high level

Answer (score 1):

I believe that to some extent - yes. You could imagine that iterator structure has a field for storing filters and only on a fence point - `map()` in your example - it evaluates filters.

As filters are closures in Rust, the language runtime has no way to evaluate them before compilation. But it could do some heuristics, for example, what comes to mind, evaluate each of the stored filters on one (few) elements to calculate its cost. Then it could rearrange them from low cost to high cost.

Bear in mind I don't know if such approach could bring any improvements to speed.